# Google forms. Send email based on answer. Error on namedValues

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, typeerror

Let me preface this by saying I do not know javascript (it's the next thing I'm learning).

I'm working with google forms and I want to send an email after form submission based on one of the answers. 
I have a table in the sheet named 'emails' that has two columns, a site column and a corresponding email. I want to send an email to whomever manages the site selected in the form. 
I setup a trigger and then have an onFormSubmit function and I've literally stripped it down to just try to get

```
function onFormSubmit(e){
    var values = e.namedValues;
    Logger.log(e);
}
```

And it will only return "TypeError: Cannot read property 'namedValues' of undefined
    at onFormSubmit(Code:2:23)"

This is the last little bit of code I threw in there hoping to just get anything out and got the same namedValues error.

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
    var responses = e.namedValues;

  // If the question title is a label, it can be accessed as an object field.
  // If it has spaces or other characters, it can be accessed as a dictionary.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('emails');
  var last = ss.getLastRow();
  var data = ss.getRange(1,1,last,2).getValues();// create an array of data from columns A and B
  var valB = e.namedValues['Site'][0];
  for(nn=0;nn<data.length;++nn){
    if (data[nn][0]==valB){break} ;// if a match in column A is found, break the loop
      }
  var sm_email = (data[nn][1]);// return Site Managers Email Address (hopefully)
  //GmailApp.sendEmail(sm_email, 'Test', 'Please Just Let This Work');
  Logger.log(sm_email);
}
```

Comment: I've already reviewed the first four links on that search. I'm pushing 3 hours or so I've googling and going through StackOverflow threads. I'm sure there's just some fundamental thing that I don't know or understand that I'm doing wrong.

Comment: the event you trigger obviously does not have the namedValues so we need to check what event it is

Comment: Here are some steps to take: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50881772/295783